# How can I get data instantly with ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, comet

I am trying to get data instantly with ajax, but I couldn't. The problem is, when I make a request, response is coming end of the php process. I want to get data after every echo command. So here is the simple example. There is two files, main html file (included javascript) and php file.

try.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Get Data</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function makeObject() {
    var newObject;
    var browser = navigator.appName;
    if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
        newObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else {
        newObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    if (newObject.overrideMimeType) {
        newObject.overrideMimeType('text/xml; charset=UTF-8;');
    }   
    return newObject;
}

var newOne=makeObject();

function getData()
{
    newOne.open('get','process.php',true);
    newOne.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (newOne.readyState==4)
        {
            var box=document.getElementById("queryResult");
            box.innerHTML=newOne.responseText;
        }
    }
    newOne.send(null);
}
</script>
</head>    
<body>
<input type="button" id="doit" value="Start Query" onclick="getData();" />
<div id="queryResult"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and process.php

```
<?php
echo "1";
sleep(1);
echo "2";
sleep(1);
echo "3";
sleep(1);
echo "4";
sleep(1);
echo "5";
?>
```

when I click the Start Query button, it is waiting 4 seconds and then write 12345 at the same time. I want to write 1 and wait 1 sec then write 2 and wait 1 sec then write 3 etc. How can I do that? Sorry for my English, thanks for the answers :)

Comment: Your entire `<?php ?>` code is lumped together at the same time. Your `echo` command does not send out to the client, but to the data queue that will be sent to the client all at once.

Comment: What do you actually want to accomplish? This could probably be done by fiddling with PHP's output buffering, but that's probably not how you should be doing whatever it is you're wanting to do.

Comment: make all these delays in JS, not PHP.

Comment: I think you should do the delay part in JavaScript, while either requesting the whole dataset at the beginning or send a new request after each JS-timeout/-interval.

Comment: I actually want to send mail at php side. After every mail sent, it will echo for ex. "Mail was/wasn't sent example@example.com successfully." I can make this different way, such as, getData function takes a parameter and send it to php, so when I called the function only 1 mail sent. And when the response come, it calls itself different parameter. I thought that use so much data traffic. Am I right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest read progressive data not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818293/xmlhttprequest-read-progressive-data-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

ajax waits for a response, so you are making the final response wait. you would have to do seperate requests. Possibly set subsequent request of dependant upon the result of the previous one(s).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an html5 web socket. Using standard ajax will not return until the request has completed.

Answer (score 0):

your code is doing exactly what you ask. The ajax response is supplied to you on the client side when the last byte is received not as it is received.

if you are after progress from the server side to appear on the client side then the client must poll and the server maintain a some state to respond, not as you have it with the server trying to send a stream response. The new HTML5 client side sockets may help you here where rather than polling the client can be called by the server

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you will need to make 4 ajax method calls.  Since you are expecting different values from each call you need to have the state saved somewhere (on client or server) so that you know which call you are on.  If the pauses in your sample are part of your intended program (and not just for the sake of the sample) then it would probably be better in your client-side Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Servers buffer their output - sending a single character is extraordinarly wasteful of network resources. To force PHP and the webserver to flush their buffers, you need at least:

```
echo "1";
flush();
ob_flush();
echo "2";
etc...
```

Comment: That sends it through the socket, but it will still just buffer on the client until the request has completed. It will only make it slower.

Comment: Unfortunately, XMLHttpRequest does not support progressive download. When the readyState is 3 (meaning content has been sent by the server but not entirely), attempting to read the response will return an error. You can only read the response when the readyState is 4, which means the full response headers and body are available.